# Flask Nginx url_for _external

Tags: python, nginx, flask

How does one make the server name replace the localhost when using `url_for` with `_external = True` (so: `url_for('foobar', _external=True)`) under Nginx?

I'm running a flask application.

### nginx setting

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/simplemadetutor.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/simplemadetutor.error.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/implemad/www/simplemadetutor/app/static;
    }
    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /home/implemad/www/simplemadetutor/app/static/img/favicon.ico;
    }
}
```

the problem is if i type `url_for('main.index', _external=True)` instead of seeing something like `http://simplemadetutor.com` I see  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

I have tried setting SERVER_NAME = 'simplemadetutor.com'; however, this seem to put the simplemadetutor.com in front of every url generated by url_for extead of just the ones with external=True.

Comment: When you set SERVER_NAME Flask will always build a full URL, even if _external=False.